# How do I Google search only Images using Python? (webbrowser module)

Tags: python, image, url, google-search, google-image-search

Is there a way how I can search only images on google, how do I construct a URL for that?

```
query="raccoon"
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open(f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}")
```

How do I make it to show only images in the result?

Comment: `f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query}&tbm=isch"`

Comment: @BenoîtZu Thanks

Comment: you should open `image searching` in browser and copy link to your code - and next you can remove parameters to see which one you really need in url.